# How to get decimal portion of a number in a decimal format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get remainder part from a decimal number. I have used `PARSENAME` function like:

```
DECLARE @Total decimal(7,2) = 1000.40;
DECLARE @Remainder int = 0;

SET @Remainder = PARSENAME(@Total, 1)
```

It is returning integer form of the decimal portion like 40. How can I get the remainder in decimal form like 0.40. Because I have to store the remainder value as a decimal.

Thanks

Partha

Comment: Do you think the fact that you're using an `int` datatype for the "Reminder" might be a bit of a problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mod function in SQL Server is `%` and anything MOD 1 is just the decimal remainder.

`SELECT DecimalPortion = 1000.40 % 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Total decimal(7,2) = 1000.40

DECLARE @Remainder decimal(2,2)

SET @Remainder = @Total - FLOOR(@Total)

SELECT @Remainder
```

simply subtracting the FLOOR of the input variable will give you the decimal portion

also per Tab's comment you do have the wrong data type for the @Remainder it should be a decimal.  If you want it as an integer there are some other methods of accomplishing that too.